# asp.net Button Image align

Tags: asp.net, css, button

I have an ASP.net button with an image. I am not nor do i want to use an Imagebutton. It is a standard asp.net button. Image loads perfect but:

1. i would like the image to align vertically in the center of the
   button
2. I would like the image to be 5 px from the left edge of
   the button

is this possible?
thanks
Damo

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button CssClass="Button" ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

**CSS**

```
.Button
{


         -moz-border-radius: 5px;
         -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
         -khtml-border-radius: 5px; 
          border-radius: 5px; 

          text-align:left;


          padding-left:20px;       
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-image: url(/assets/img/action.gif);

}
```

Comment: try background-position attribute http://goo.gl/9NVc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the image size..

But here you get the code,

```
.button{
background: url(/assets/img/action.gif) no-repeat 5px 50%;
padding:5px 5px 5px 20px;
border-radius:5px;
text-align:left;
}
```